# Links aren't detected automatically when in parentheses

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks

Look at this answer:

[How can I view title text for a web image (xkcd.com) on an Android based browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/how-can-i-view-alt-text-for-a-web-image-xkcd-com-on-an-android-based-browser/2048#2048)

It has a link, but it is in parentheses:

(http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200604/alt_text_is_an_alternative_not_a_tooltip/)

Markdown isn't converting this into a link correctly.

When I move the parentheses a bit, it does:

( http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200604/alt_text_is_an_alternative_not_a_tooltip/ )

I haven't seen this documented as a feature yet, so I'm guessing it's a bug.

Comment: @Ladybug: your edit should have been an _answer_ to the question (or a comment), I guess.

Comment: @Ladybug: your edit is precisely what I wanted to avoid.  The link should have been detected automatically, just like the second example.  I unrolled your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auto-linking of URLs directly after an opening parenthesis (or, for that matter, any non-word character) will work after the next build. The original Markdown requires a whitespace character before an auto-linked URL, but I don't really agree with that (and in comments, this has already worked for a long time).

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this should not be a link, feel free to compare it yourself in a skadillion different Markdown engines:

http://goo.gl/D1QgA

In no case is that converted to a link. But putting it in `<` `>` should work:

> It has a link, but it is in parentheses:
>
> (http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200604/alt_text_is_an_alternative_not_a_tooltip/)