# The markdown isn't automatically taking an Stack Overflow question between ( )

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, linked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links aren't detected automatically when in parentheses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81878/links-arent-detected-automatically-when-in-parentheses)

Take a look at the following question:

[image]

As you can see there, the linked question wasn't automatically converted to

[XOM getting attribute from Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363599/xom-getting-attribute-from-node)

Is this a known problem, or some kind of bug?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a "known problem", or at least I've known about it for a long time. Hard to say whether it's considered a bug...

The problem, of course, lies in the parentheses. The reason it works correctly in your question is because you've posted the link on a line of its own without surrounding it in parentheses. In the original question, the one you show a screenshot of, the poster surrounded the URL in parentheses, preventing the markdown system from automatically converting it to a named link.

I assume that the parentheses can potentially conflict with the markdown syntax used for links, involving square braces and parentheses. Probably not worth fixing, it's more helpful to add descriptions to inline links (such as those that might appear within parentheses), rather than simply the name of the target question. It reads much more naturally that way.

Demonstration:

[XOM getting attribute from Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363599/xom-getting-attribute-from-node)

([XOM getting attribute from Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363599/xom-getting-attribute-from-node))