# Markdown links and images are producing incorrect HTML

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks, images

The problem appeared *recently*.

[image: What happened to me?]

Images and [links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528430) are not displayed correctly.

Comment: Weird! It's filtering out it's own markup, someone reversed the HTML filter?

Comment: One-boxing in chat is also gone.

Comment: Does it really get any more *meta* than this? The question itself is demoing the question.

Comment: @phant0m: production is testing.

Comment: @phant0m, the word you're looking for is *agile*.

Comment: Couldn't resist creating a meta-screenshot for posterity: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NSSAE.png

Comment: Rushing a fix out for this, eta 10 minutes.

Comment: Let's in the mean time [assign some blame](http://bit.ly/pYtBLT).

Comment: @KevinMontrose When this fixes, does this revert the changes in edits or are those already set in stone?

Comment: @Bart I am so easily amused.

Comment: Yay it's fixed?

Comment: @mellamokb a fix is rolling out, it's not quite everywhere yet.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Pfff, grow up will y...oh weeeeeeeeeeeeeee!!!

Comment: As a similar site says, "Thank you for you are patients".

Comment: @ikegami - Haha. Though I think that should be "you're". Just sounds and looks better.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[image: oops]

This was entirely my screw-up. Here's what happened.

The problematic change was [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81878/links-arent-detected-automatically-when-in-parentheses/165063#165063). Ironically the [much larger Markdown change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66472/url-detecting-error-with-address-like-http-en-wikipedia-org-wiki-octet-compu/165064#165064) I made yesterday did not break anything.

This is how Markdown handles links:

1. Replace all advanced Markdown-syntax links and images (like `[foo](http://bar.baz)` and `![quux][1]`  with their corresponding `<a href="...">` and `<img src="...">` HTML.
2. Magic.
3. Replace the simple Markdown link syntax, whereby you place URLs between angle brackets (`<http://google.com>`), with their corresponding `<a href="...">` HTML.

The "Magic" step is the auto-linking – take anything that looks like a plain link, and put it between angle brackets, so that step 3 will turn it into real HTML links.

Before I made the change, step 2 only handled URLs that were preceded by a whitespace character, which is why the fairly common idea of putting a link in parentheses:

```
A company called Google (http://google.com) runs a search engine.
```

never worked as expected – an open parenthesis is not a whitespace character.

The change I made was to allow any non-word character before the URL instead. Which was a horribly stupid idea (and in fact, I had previously shied away from this change because of exactly this problem – but for some reason, this didn't enter my mind yesterday until all hell broke loose).

Imagine this Markdown source:

```
[This website](http://rolex-watches.scam) is great.
```

After step 1, the intermediate HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="http://rolex-watches.scam">This website</a> is great.
```

Now comes step 2. Before my change, it wouldn't touch anything here, because the `http://` was not preceded by a whitespace character. After my change, it did indeed touch it, because guess what – *a quote sign is a non-word character:*

```
<a href="<http://rolex-watches.scam>">This website</a> is great.
```

Now comes step three (linebreak added for readability):

```
<a href="<a href="http://rolex-watches.scam">http://rolex-watches.scam</a>">This
    website</a> is great.
```

Then the HTML sanitizer removes the illegal "tag" from the first `<` to the first `>`, leaving

```
http://rolex-watches.scam</a>">This website</a> is great.
```

and finally the tag balancer removes the two closing `</a>`s, because they have no corresponding opening tags:

```
http://rolex-watches.scam">This website is great.
```

– and that's what you saw.

So (except for just forgetting this issue despite having previously considered it), why didn't I realize this problem?

Well, the test post I played with while testing had no Markdown-syntax links, just bare URLs. So step 1 never did anything, and nothing broke.

I also ran the test suite in MarkdownSharp, and it didn't report any issues with the change either. Why? Because unfortunately, step 2 is a configurable option in MarkdownSharp, and *turned off by default*. And most tests run with the default options. And those few test cases that enable this option *only* test the auto-linking – they don't have any links for step 1 either.

[Kevin backed my change out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165096/markdown-links-and-images-are-producing-incorrect-html/165100#165100), since he felt that unbroken Markdown would be a nice thing to have, and I tend to agree with that.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81878/links-arent-detected-automatically-when-in-parentheses) is thus not completed at the moment, but it will be again after the next build. I've changed step 2 to require a URL to be preceded by a non-word character *and neither by `="` nor by `<`* to be eligible for auto-linking.

And just to be sure, this time I have not only run the tests with the option on; I have also tested the change against a couple of thousand real-world questions and answers to make sure that the only differences in rendering are intended ones.

Comment: I think your fix may also broke [links that have a second http:// in it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165274/link-parser-can-not-handle-urls-with-a-second-http-in-it-request-to-re-open)

Answer (score 15):

A fix for this has been deployed. It looks like some recent changes to the [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) rendering pipeline went sideways.

Affected posts will display incorrect HTML until they're edited (as we cache the rendered Markdown)... which means I'm going to be poking a bunch of posts for the next hour or so.

---

Poking completed, all affected posts should have been corrected.  If you see anything left over, let me know.

Comment: Uh oh, he stole Rebecca's stick!

Comment: You'll be poking on all sites, right? Because I saw this issue on more than SO and MSO.

Comment: @AlEverett yep, I've found all the affected posts across all sites.  About to start the cleanup.

Comment: I don't know what went wrong yet (I'm not near a computer right now), but I take all the blame proactively.

Comment: Argh, I know what happened now. I still take the blame :)

Comment: Just curious: did you ever consider building the cooked HTML cache upon first request, *if* the cache does not exist? Then clearing the cache for affected posts would mark for rebuilding, without any peak load to regenerate HTML for all those posts.

Comment: @Arjan Rebaking a few hundred or thousand posts doesn't cause any kind of problematic load.

Comment: Ah, then [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104856/more-and-more-images-go-missing-can-the-cooked-html-be-rebuilt) took you boys & girls too long too fix, @balpha ;-) (Thanks for the insight, as usual. Much appreciated!)