# Link parser can not handle URLs with a second http:// in it

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks

### Escaped version

```
The following [link][1] does not work, neither does <a href="http://web.archive.org/web/20121130000728/http://www.google.com/">this</a>.

[1]: http://web.archive.org/web/20121130000728/http://www.google.com/
```

### Formatted version

The following [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20121130000728/http://www.google.com/) does not work, neither does [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20121130000728/http://www.google.com/).

(The screenshot due to the above text now displays correctly after the fix was applied.)
[image]

Comment: It looks fine in the edit preview, though.

Comment: Yea, that's the weirdest part.

Comment: I don't think it is weird, if the edit preview is generated with JS. The main post is converted from Markdown to HTML on server.

Comment: Funny, it seems to work in [comments](http://web.archive.org/web/20121130000728/http://www.google.com/).

Comment: @nhahtdh Differences between live preview and actual post formatting are [by design](http://meta.superuser.com/a/1755/22317)

Comment: @DanielBeck No, they're not, not at this level. Things like this should be identical.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I figured adding a screenshot for *future* reference would be nice, but it seems that the edit also made the HTML for *this* very question work nicely. However, @balpha, the problem still exists with URLs in query parameters? See [Link working in preview but not on post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175448/link-working-in-preview-but-not-on-post).

Comment: @Arjan That's a mainly unrelated issue, but yeah, fixing. Regarding "screenshot for future reference" -- meh. Who cares about this in the future?

Comment: If it doesn't come back, then probably nobody, @balpha :-) (Even if it does come back, if I were developing this, then I'd rather have the exact HTML output instead of a screen capture, but this Arjan guy is a bit lazy `;-)`)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Discourse on regular expressions ahead. If you don't care for such a thing, just know that this is fixed in the next build.

---

Ah yes, the neverending story of link-within-a-link creation. We have several unpretty hacks in place to prevent this in multiple areas. Could just add another one for this new case.

> There's a few ways of fixing it, but all this escaping and encoding problem characters is getting a bit messy, so I'm not sure what the best approach is.

So true, [Tim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165274/link-parser-can-not-handle-urls-with-a-second-http-in-it#comment482549_165290).

> It looks fine in the edit preview, though.

Hmm, you're right, [nhahtdh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165274/link-parser-can-not-handle-urls-with-a-second-http-in-it#comment482497_165274). Now why would that be?

The reason for this is what is usually a deficiency in JavaScript regular expressions: They don't support lookbehinds.

I say "usually", because in this case, this gave me the idea for a fix that's much cleaner than doing yet another "encoding problem characters" step.

So the change to allow auto-linking of URLs preceded by a non-word character and neither by `="` nor by `<` (which, despite all the havoc I've created with it so far, I still consider a good change), was implemented differently in the [server-side Markdown version](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) and in the [client-side version](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/). .NET regexes do support lookbehinds, so on the server it was as simple as

```
(?<!<|=")
```

For the JavaScript version, I had to *simulate* a negative lookbehind by using

```
(<|=")?
```

and by not handling a match if this group was matched.

Simulating lookbehinds this way has a disadvantage: The match also consumes these preceding characters; it's not a zero-width assertion. That's not a problem in this case though.

There's a second difference though. Imagine the following:

```
<a href="http://foo.com/http://bar.com">
       ^ ^              ^            ^
       A B              C            D
```

When walking through this string, the server-side version doesn't match at B, because of the lookbehind. It continues on through the string, and finds a match at C, which is not preceded by `="`, and auto-links the part between C and D. Not what we like.

The JavaScript version on the other hand matches the full thing from A to D. It leaves it unchanged, because the `(<|=")?` group was matched, but the important thing is: This match *consumes the whole part from A to D*. And thus the inner link from C to D is never touched.

From the next build on, the server-side version does the same thing as the client-side version. And I would never have believed I'd one day say "I'm glad that JavaScript regular expressions don't support lookbehinds".

Comment: In the 2 regex examples, shouldn't `=""` part be `="` as raw regex (regex without string escaping or escaping due to delimiters)?

Comment: @nhahtdh Ah yeah, thanks. Copy&paste error.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that the recent [Markdown breakdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165096) also broke this feature.

> I've changed step 2 to require a URL to be preceded by a non-word character and neither by `="` nor by `<` to be eligible for auto-linking.

Judging from the fact that the broken HTML is only showing the `http://www.google.com/` part, I'd say that the "fixed" Step 2 there is causing angled brackets to be placed in spots where they do not belong again, creating something like this:

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20121130000728/<http://www.google.com/>
```

After all, a `/` is not a forbidden character. ;P

Comment: Good find, thanks! I put a link to this question as a comment to the dev so they can add it to the unit test too.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue. There's a few ways of fixing it, but all this escaping and encoding problem characters is getting a bit messy, so I'm not sure what the best approach is.