# param args with single quotes not accepted as allowed html on SE and Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs

It's quite annoying that single quotes are deemed unacceptable html on all StackExchange sites, including Careers 2.0.

Why is `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>` ok, but `<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow</a>` is not?

In other words, why is [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) ok, but http://stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow is not?

Note that this has already been discussed in terms of SE ([Allow single quotes in link when writing question or answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169706/allow-single-quotes-in-link-when-writing-question-or-answer)), but I think that the context of Careers 2.0 is different, because one would expect to be able to copy-paste snippets of their existing manually-handcrafted XHTML resume into Careers 2.0 with ease, and anything that inhibits such an initiative might as well leave a Careers 2.0 profile outdated and underused.

Comment: You could use Markdown for this.

Comment: @Asad read the last paragraph

Comment: Where exactly are you pasting this?  All of the cv fields are amrkdown entry so I wouldn't expect cutting and pasting html snippets including anchors to work anywhere.

Comment: @NickLarsen, I don't know what you're talking about.  The `a` tags work, provided there are double quotes on `href`, and even the `title` param is supported.