# snippets from XHTML CV require way too many changes for Careers 2.0

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I've copy-pasted a bunch of snippets from my XHTML resume onto my new Careers 2.0 profile, and it required a lot of changes:

- single quotes in links didn't work ([param args with single quotes not accepted as allowed html on SE and Careers 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178721/param-args-with-single-quotes-not-accepted-as-allowed-html-on-se-and-careers-2-0)); most keywords of my open-source contributions aren't actually links on my Careers 2.0 profile because of this
- whitespace at the start of each line makes XHTML snippets interpreted as code; that's just wrong, and requires quite a lot of editing; why would anyone be posting code snippets on Careers 2.0?  I'd think it'd be more useful if snippets from an XHTML CV could instead be pasted without any extra hassle
- it seems like line breaks within `a` tags are not allowed; some of my links have the `title` param, and thus occupy more than one line in my XHTML resume (the linebreak was not within `title`, just within the `a` tag)

It would be nice if these issues are resolved, so that it'll be possible to paste snippets from XHTML resumes directly into Careers 2.0, without any extra hassles.

Comment: I think using the same markdown everywhere is preferable. But having some form of html to html+markdown helper could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

We use markdown as the entry mechanism for most of the fields on profiles, not XHTML.  Markdown has significant whitespace and special syntax for links (and images) so I wouldn't expect the copied snippets to transfer over.

There are a few attempts to write [css which converts your html to markdown using css](http://mrcoles.com/demo/markdown-css/) but outside of that it's probably faster to just rewrite the parts of your profile you intend to copy over in markdown.

Comment: I don't know why you claim that XHTML is not supported; certainly a subset of XHTML is; I even got `<ul>` and `<li>` to work, provided they're not preceded by whitespace on the same line.  I realise you can't modify the meaning of existing fields, so, perhaps it would be helpful if you introduce a new tag, perhaps `<html>`, which would allow copy-paste of XHTML snippets, situated within markdown's `<html>` tag.  Basically, you'll only have to turn off the non-XHTML part of markdown within `<html>`, leaving the rest as usual.