# Link working in preview but not on post

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-rendering

The following link:

[link](http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enKR434KR434&biw=1711&bih=968&tbm=isch&tbnid=f6FEHFZbuQzV6M:&imgrefurl=http://blogs.webex.com/webex_interactions/2010/08/bear_grylls_everest.html&docid=Z_wVDhYxhn3jvM&imgurl=http://blogs.webex.com/.a/6a00d83451c08e69e20133f2de805b970b-pi&w=4103&h=494&ei=B-pfUZOcOeioiAeMiYCADA&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:5,s:0,i:96&iact=rc&dur=1647&page=1&tbnh=41&tbnw=310&start=0&ndsp=31&tx=87&ty=10)

does not work. The code is:

```
[link][2]


[2]: http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enKR434KR434&biw=1711&bih=968&tbm=isch&tbnid=f6FEHFZbuQzV6M:&imgrefurl=http://blogs.webex.com/webex_interactions/2010/08/bear_grylls_everest.html&docid=Z_wVDhYxhn3jvM&imgurl=http://blogs.webex.com/.a/6a00d83451c08e69e20133f2de805b970b-pi&w=4103&h=494&ei=B-pfUZOcOeioiAeMiYCADA&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:5,s:0,i:96&iact=rc&dur=1647&page=1&tbnh=41&tbnw=310&start=0&ndsp=31&tx=87&ty=10
```

It works fine in the preview, and I have already tried `encodeURI()`ing it. Here's an example of where this link breaks: [Why does the sky look black in pictures taken from the summit of everest?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60226/why-does-the-sky-look-black-in-pictures-taken-from-the-summit-of-everest)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165274/link-parser-can-not-handle-urls-with-a-second-http-in-it

Comment: As an aside: I wonder how future-proof [such link](http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enKR434KR434&biw=1711&bih=968&tbm=isch&tbnid=f6FEHFZbuQzV6M:&imgrefurl=http://blogs.webex.com/webex_interactions/2010/08/bear_grylls_everest.html&docid=Z_wVDhYxhn3jvM&imgurl=http://blogs.webex.com/.a/6a00d83451c08e69e20133f2de805b970b-pi&w=4103&h=494&ei=B-pfUZOcOeioiAeMiYCADA&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:5,s:0,i:96&iact=rc&dur=1647&page=1&tbnh=41&tbnw=310&start=0&ndsp=31&tx=87&ty=10) is. It looks nice, but I'd use https://www.google.com/search?q=view+from+top+of+everest&tbm=isch ("image search").

Comment: ([Screen capture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fN0ac.png) for future reference.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fixed](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=30f954c6e66fbf37cf3af5b1eba125c58ef4bfae) in the next build. The problem here wasn't so much the link-within-the-link (it just made the problem very visible), but the underscore. Markdown escapes certain characters (like the underscore) in links, to prevent them from being treated as formatting characters. The two Markdown implementations use different escape characters for this: the client-side version uses a tilde, the server-side version uses U+001A. The former is a legal character for being auto-linked, but the latter was not. That's why the behaviors were differing.