# Link works in edit view, but not in the rendered post

Tags: bug, markdown-preview

Yes, [this happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175448), and is marked as fixed, so this must be a reversion (or a subtly different bug).

<kbd>[image: Screenshot of edit view]</kbd>

The first link within the parentheses (the second link in the post) works in the live preview in edit mode but not in the rendered post.

Comment: Any particular reason for the `<kbd>` tags, @Martijn?

Comment: Nicer framing for the image; I prefer it over using a blockquote or no framing at all (where it then looks part of the page).

Comment: @Martijn :( Vote For Blockquote! It is beautiful to have image of this size wrapped in blockquotes.

Comment: That makes a fair deal of sense, actually, @Martijn.

Comment: @nicael: but that won't work on mobile, while [using kbd does](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270195).

Comment: @Martijn Was there a proposal to grey the background of blockquotes in mobile or I can create one? :)

Comment: @nicael: no idea, knock yourself out.