# Link in answer editor appears correctly in preview, but not in the answer

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

**Note:** I know about the other bug marked duplicate, but this one is different.

I was about to edit an answer to fix url syntax, but noticed that it was correct. Preview thinks it is correct, but there's no `ref` in the answer. The answer I was going to edit is
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4262450/1045994

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because this answer was posted before I made [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165063/115866), and so its HTML was still created under the old rules, where a URL directly following an opening parenthesis would not be auto-linked. I have made a non-edit to the answer (just added a newline) to force re-rendering the answer with the new rules, and now the URLs are links.

Comment: Ahh ok, cool thanks for answering.